# How do I stop html contents sent through Apps Script from having too much paddings?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

After sending the emails, on the user end the email has too much padding on the top, right, left and bottom. So, I’m trying to resolve the padding issues.

This is the code I’m using now to get the HTML contents from google docs;

`var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + emailBodyTemplateId + "&exportFormat=html";

var param = {
method: "get",
headers: {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
},
muteHttpExceptions: true,
};

}
var messageBody = emailBodyForResponse || UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();`

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a Google Doc to html, the margins of the document are retained as padding. Try setting the margins of your template document to 0.